# Add Open Graph Data from MySQL in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, joomla3.0

I have a web site built in Joomla 3.x, and I am using it to store recipes. It stores recipes in MySQL database.

[Link to Site](https://www.yapalimyiyelim.com/index.php)

I am using single PHP page to show any recipe, and because of this, I am not able to update page title, or open graph metadata's in page, as they already loaded in Joomla before my PHP article page is loading.

Is there any way to load these metadata in header from MySQL ? I am searching solution for this very long time, I tried many plugins but never succeed.

Thanks a  lot

Comment: They've answered this in the Joomla community: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/how-can-i-set-the-page-heading-via-the-joomla-api

Comment: Hi Webaholik, I manage to do it, thanks a lot. I was really looking for this very long time. You can share this as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$this->params->set('page_heading', "My New Title");
```

As answered in the Joomla community: 
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/how-can-i-set-the-page-heading-via-the-joomla-api